# What list is most likely to have the lowest median?

Tags: probability

I'm currently working on an optimisation problem where a simulation can be run with several parameters and I need to find which parameters are the best. Since each simulation takes a long time to run, I need to discard bad sets of parameters as soon as possible.

Each simulation is scored (lower is better), and the results are added to a list.

For example, for four different setups, the simulation values are:

```
[0.31771960854530334, 0.3411135673522949, 0.3310917615890503, 0.3159765601158142, 0.33600446581840515, 0.3352251946926117, 0.33761146664619446, 0.32225948572158813, 0.3350348472595215, 0.3457653820514679, 0.32325679063796997, 0.326958030462265, 0.3291585445404053, 0.3235035836696625, 0.3258521854877472, 0.3204689919948578, 0.3229052722454071, 0.315879225730896, 0.31862542033195496, 0.33796921372413635, 0.32604268193244934, 0.34038183093070984, 0.3183555006980896, 0.3175279498100281, 0.32143139839172363, 0.3224892318248749, 0.34159010648727417, 0.33131226897239685, 0.3263885974884033, 0.31594401597976685, 0.3327217102050781, 0.32813698053359985, 0.3278810679912567, 0.31822341680526733, 0.34068915247917175, 0.32860109210014343, 0.33968520164489746, 0.3319733440876007, 0.32811060547828674, 0.31651514768600464, 0.32799118757247925, 0.31894755363464355, 0.3412730395793915, 0.32626068592071533, 0.3176010847091675, 0.33038097620010376, 0.3207707405090332, 0.31058192253112793, 0.3066112995147705, 0.3303760886192322, 0.3223210871219635, 0.33629271388053894, 0.33516937494277954, 0.3147951066493988, 0.3211946189403534, 0.32553717494010925, 0.333586722612381, 0.31509238481521606, 0.3251512944698334, 0.33351272344589233, 0.3334641754627228, 0.3285764455795288, 0.31418612599372864, 0.31757283210754395, 0.3138282001018524, 0.33097517490386963, 0.3072074055671692, 0.330384761095047, 0.32259663939476013, 0.33039024472236633, 0.33015933632850647, 0.30926862359046936, 0.32790517807006836, 0.3298207223415375, 0.32572630047798157, 0.3271850645542145, 0.3353654742240906, 0.33518925309181213, 0.3298708498477936, 0.31685906648635864, 0.32341158390045166, 0.3397740125656128, 0.3357153832912445, 0.33256030082702637, 0.3344813585281372, 0.3193385601043701, 0.3442055583000183, 0.3175262212753296, 0.3320333957672119, 0.3278960585594177, 0.31660929322242737, 0.33225393295288086, 0.31808194518089294, 0.3276512920856476, 0.3289024829864502, 0.3260359764099121, 0.31691187620162964, 0.31895992159843445, 0.32702019810676575, 0.3133307695388794, 0.33777090907096863, 0.31016212701797485, 0.3192517161369324, 0.3378731608390808, 0.33338403701782227, 0.33280327916145325, 0.3471103310585022, 0.3226596415042877, 0.32838064432144165, 0.32759958505630493, 0.32864367961883545, 0.32859107851982117, 0.3304615914821625, 0.3392229378223419, 0.31688782572746277, 0.3223646581172943, 0.3196653127670288, 0.3321816623210907, 0.3239646852016449, 0.33385634422302246, 0.3212287425994873, 0.341138631105423, 0.33112257719039917, 0.33745497465133667, 0.328122079372406, 0.3257265090942383, 0.3174751400947571, 0.3313937783241272, 0.3291671872138977, 0.3429141938686371, 0.3296595811843872, 0.3168943226337433, 0.31397369503974915, 0.3285788595676422, 0.3362148702144623, 0.3139144480228424, 0.33292356133461, 0.3266337215900421, 0.3262031078338623, 0.3298202455043793, 0.3371160328388214, 0.3162180483341217, 0.3364160656929016, 0.3440856337547302, 0.33859172463417053, 0.3409537672996521, 0.3220680058002472, 0.3370307981967926, 0.32390737533569336, 0.3329233229160309, 0.33171454071998596, 0.32725751399993896, 0.3364013135433197, 0.31892862915992737, 0.32104170322418213, 0.33342257142066956, 0.324175089597702, 0.3192666172981262, 0.32224178314208984, 0.33359402418136597, 0.32298949360847473, 0.32580050826072693, 0.3253556787967682, 0.32010194659233093, 0.32726871967315674, 0.31733739376068115, 0.34169745445251465, 0.3263677954673767, 0.31995689868927, 0.316768616437912, 0.32777139544487, 0.357673317193985, 0.3344147503376007, 0.32023680210113525, 0.34205177426338196, 0.33622756600379944, 0.3366716504096985, 0.31310343742370605, 0.33088022470474243, 0.3324989378452301, 0.3340208828449249, 0.33667221665382385, 0.33015182614326477, 0.3351299464702606, 0.3493722081184387, 0.35016506910324097, 0.31731393933296204, 0.3396014869213104, 0.33443284034729004, 0.3282649517059326, 0.32744741439819336, 0.3251930773258209, 0.3237573206424713, 0.33440178632736206, 0.31835541129112244, 0.3139073848724365, 0.33747008442878723, 0.3255719542503357, 0.3291328549385071, 0.3283381462097168, 0.326183021068573, 0.3443581759929657, 0.32772335410118103, 0.3262929916381836, 0.3197605013847351, 0.3139354884624481, 0.3296361267566681, 0.32264745235443115, 0.3289695084095001, 0.311590313911438, 0.3294873535633087, 0.3286621570587158, 0.33963173627853394, 0.32591935992240906, 0.3243439197540283, 0.346100777387619, 0.3155832886695862, 0.3194901943206787, 0.3262616991996765, 0.3232318162918091, 0.32922855019569397, 0.33100077509880066, 0.329399436712265, 0.32703420519828796, 0.31251150369644165, 0.3232514262199402, 0.325417697429657, 0.32872843742370605, 0.32970234751701355, 0.325783371925354, 0.32775282859802246, 0.3299684226512909, 0.3423644006252289, 0.31883227825164795, 0.3266981244087219, 0.32093918323516846, 0.32331332564353943, 0.3233243227005005, 0.33228716254234314, 0.31604820489883423, 0.3312731981277466, 0.32008159160614014, 0.3313177227973938, 0.33330607414245605, 0.32773950695991516, 0.323442667722702, 0.3311300277709961, 0.32210227847099304, 0.3235970437526703, 0.33470338582992554, 0.3385612666606903]
[0.3267229199409485, 0.32743632793426514, 0.3379046320915222, 0.3192898631095886, 0.3243163824081421, 0.31881511211395264, 0.33305877447128296, 0.3382623791694641, 0.31462612748146057, 0.3215361535549164, 0.323795348405838, 0.3384469747543335, 0.32207536697387695, 0.3416607677936554, 0.31890445947647095, 0.3318520486354828, 0.34684109687805176, 0.3353455662727356, 0.3477597236633301, 0.32024338841438293, 0.34402525424957275, 0.32256367802619934, 0.3309565782546997, 0.33743816614151, 0.3308350145816803, 0.3184194564819336, 0.33140555024147034, 0.31232574582099915, 0.30976834893226624, 0.3154352605342865, 0.3383341133594513, 0.3322511315345764, 0.3395189344882965, 0.31730926036834717, 0.33276185393333435, 0.3410451114177704, 0.3145223557949066, 0.3371468782424927, 0.34231001138687134, 0.3266512155532837, 0.3317577540874481, 0.3369251787662506, 0.33937856554985046, 0.3243086338043213, 0.33703064918518066, 0.3240451514720917, 0.32600873708724976, 0.3160380721092224, 0.32518136501312256, 0.34050101041793823, 0.31199783086776733, 0.32796674966812134, 0.3090508282184601, 0.3316683769226074, 0.3190543055534363, 0.3295072317123413, 0.32485708594322205, 0.32997167110443115, 0.3235652446746826, 0.33609041571617126, 0.3368695080280304, 0.3402504026889801, 0.33218008279800415, 0.3152736723423004, 0.32928070425987244, 0.32465416193008423, 0.3271172046661377, 0.3246077597141266, 0.3263513743877411, 0.3309141993522644, 0.3227037489414215, 0.32698488235473633, 0.34095796942710876, 0.3373194932937622, 0.32564684748649597, 0.3281288146972656, 0.34161245822906494, 0.3324119746685028, 0.3160533607006073, 0.3425150513648987, 0.3319264352321625, 0.33455589413642883, 0.3432563543319702, 0.32094091176986694, 0.3395601212978363, 0.3127990961074829, 0.32510772347450256, 0.3366890251636505, 0.32935991883277893, 0.31454864144325256, 0.3233325779438019, 0.32630276679992676, 0.31492000818252563, 0.3266668915748596, 0.3274754285812378, 0.3304188549518585, 0.33483192324638367, 0.33228811621665955, 0.349879652261734, 0.33940431475639343, 0.3177168369293213, 0.3212905526161194, 0.3304230570793152, 0.3346741795539856, 0.33448565006256104, 0.3424493372440338, 0.3224787712097168, 0.3284454345703125, 0.3369140028953552, 0.30988961458206177, 0.32718050479888916, 0.3204021155834198, 0.3266516327857971, 0.3354157507419586, 0.33314698934555054, 0.32606416940689087, 0.3144015073776245, 0.32933250069618225, 0.34145551919937134, 0.3194434940814972, 0.31916865706443787, 0.32313302159309387, 0.3259444236755371, 0.3320809304714203, 0.3194102644920349, 0.3517061769962311, 0.32393112778663635, 0.3093551695346832, 0.3187052607536316, 0.33517155051231384, 0.3415912091732025, 0.34153974056243896, 0.34034159779548645, 0.3147021234035492, 0.3277668356895447, 0.3327922224998474, 0.3261421322822571, 0.3345797657966614, 0.3185528516769409, 0.3284032940864563, 0.3316884934902191, 0.332044392824173, 0.32601290941238403, 0.3254467248916626, 0.324466735124588, 0.3143446743488312, 0.3280661106109619, 0.3198263645172119, 0.33755022287368774, 0.32410794496536255, 0.33001866936683655, 0.33350929617881775, 0.3437245190143585, 0.3209250569343567, 0.32605138421058655, 0.327309250831604, 0.3251086175441742, 0.33221352100372314, 0.3134590983390808, 0.309801310300827, 0.32777610421180725, 0.3143211901187897, 0.34568271040916443, 0.3289255201816559, 0.32307568192481995, 0.3394985795021057, 0.33417317271232605, 0.35315218567848206, 0.33393919467926025, 0.3232193887233734, 0.3336452543735504, 0.31885212659835815, 0.31463339924812317, 0.33677753806114197, 0.3339676260948181, 0.320152223110199, 0.3280581533908844, 0.3307224214076996, 0.332164466381073, 0.3410584032535553, 0.3176063895225525, 0.32713887095451355, 0.3278213441371918, 0.330533891916275, 0.33382999897003174, 0.32583391666412354, 0.31684643030166626, 0.32354992628097534, 0.3226381242275238, 0.3322112560272217, 0.31852445006370544, 0.3268941342830658, 0.32859161496162415, 0.31969207525253296, 0.34099286794662476, 0.32638439536094666, 0.315696120262146, 0.34351271390914917, 0.3354894518852234, 0.32553502917289734, 0.332570880651474, 0.3274179697036743, 0.3266271948814392, 0.3194597661495209, 0.31992536783218384, 0.33337461948394775, 0.32929253578186035, 0.3233630657196045, 0.33480459451675415, 0.31341734528541565, 0.3299284279346466, 0.3140990138053894, 0.32049453258514404, 0.3212701976299286, 0.3378102779388428, 0.32193851470947266, 0.327597975730896, 0.3306169807910919, 0.3273265063762665, 0.3364575207233429, 0.3323219120502472, 0.33423301577568054, 0.32122907042503357, 0.3457379937171936, 0.3297920227050781, 0.3203602731227875, 0.32442525029182434, 0.3364064693450928, 0.32620587944984436, 0.3200381398200989, 0.326015442609787, 0.3124906122684479, 0.334214448928833, 0.3377543091773987, 0.3333757519721985, 0.3231061100959778, 0.32188844680786133, 0.324896901845932, 0.32873085141181946, 0.31589481234550476, 0.3319867253303528, 0.3147903382778168, 0.3351294696331024, 0.320241242647171, 0.3409782946109772, 0.3226363956928253, 0.3367580771446228, 0.3292776048183441, 0.33287107944488525, 0.3366411626338959, 0.3345683813095093]
[0.33624929189682007, 0.3287142515182495, 0.3282497823238373, 0.3231293261051178, 0.3276967704296112, 0.3159177303314209, 0.3232215642929077, 0.31050199270248413, 0.33882132172584534, 0.31627219915390015, 0.328301340341568, 0.323494017124176, 0.33648091554641724, 0.3302154541015625, 0.32252809405326843, 0.325831800699234, 0.3291361629962921, 0.33038660883903503, 0.3243918716907501, 0.3314204514026642, 0.31982478499412537, 0.31441012024879456, 0.31564193964004517, 0.32808980345726013, 0.3281863331794739, 0.324187695980072, 0.3282264471054077, 0.33002328872680664, 0.32661059498786926, 0.3380882441997528, 0.33419668674468994, 0.3230492174625397, 0.3348229229450226, 0.3574739694595337, 0.33011552691459656, 0.3326999843120575, 0.3287033438682556, 0.3321249186992645, 0.31782105565071106, 0.32974880933761597, 0.31068962812423706, 0.3354730010032654, 0.33830124139785767, 0.3275121748447418, 0.3350403904914856, 0.3289044201374054, 0.32169339060783386, 0.3415501117706299, 0.3231006860733032, 0.3376041054725647, 0.331894189119339, 0.3367205560207367, 0.3307500183582306, 0.32555049657821655, 0.32826390862464905, 0.32624563574790955, 0.336374968290329, 0.3409147262573242, 0.33605843782424927, 0.33033502101898193, 0.33736634254455566, 0.31489112973213196, 0.3447684347629547, 0.3127114474773407, 0.3219720423221588, 0.3324788510799408, 0.33304640650749207, 0.3233388662338257, 0.344908207654953, 0.32772520184516907, 0.3202908933162689, 0.3341575860977173, 0.3242793679237366, 0.31357690691947937, 0.342279851436615, 0.3376206159591675, 0.33145490288734436, 0.3231625556945801, 0.34458813071250916, 0.35161229968070984, 0.3341100811958313, 0.31792309880256653, 0.3350130617618561, 0.3269343078136444, 0.3274449110031128, 0.3332025110721588, 0.33890464901924133, 0.3310836851596832, 0.3260648846626282, 0.3320920169353485, 0.31796830892562866, 0.3316657841205597, 0.32678696513175964, 0.3243063986301422, 0.3389805853366852, 0.3378528952598572, 0.32963958382606506, 0.3291800022125244, 0.3229588270187378, 0.3158859610557556, 0.33378612995147705, 0.32980960607528687, 0.3314034640789032, 0.3495618999004364, 0.34350207448005676, 0.33728474378585815, 0.3223113715648651, 0.3273019790649414, 0.3375053107738495, 0.3219207525253296, 0.31646591424942017, 0.3290528655052185, 0.3236597180366516, 0.33656299114227295, 0.31681203842163086, 0.33121103048324585, 0.3391268849372864, 0.3329790234565735, 0.3316926658153534, 0.3406834602355957, 0.3411814272403717, 0.3304559290409088, 0.3344014883041382, 0.31848758459091187, 0.3220844864845276, 0.3284826874732971, 0.3178800642490387, 0.3257116675376892, 0.3284456729888916, 0.3307386338710785, 0.3249015510082245, 0.3346707224845886, 0.3350428342819214, 0.3272017538547516, 0.3285459578037262, 0.3333998918533325, 0.3338611423969269, 0.3345821499824524, 0.32539471983909607, 0.32254770398139954, 0.3264961838722229, 0.33045777678489685, 0.3462536633014679, 0.33078157901763916, 0.32030102610588074, 0.3491971492767334, 0.3487035036087036, 0.3317318260669708, 0.3164506256580353, 0.3425511419773102, 0.3261355459690094, 0.3322986662387848, 0.3051031827926636, 0.31799325346946716, 0.3363778293132782, 0.3247794210910797, 0.32316914200782776, 0.31646087765693665, 0.32941049337387085, 0.3170713484287262, 0.32127413153648376, 0.3235956132411957, 0.33041346073150635, 0.3275195360183716, 0.3408852219581604, 0.33364754915237427, 0.3346582055091858, 0.3150944411754608, 0.3334123492240906, 0.32507532835006714, 0.3130708932876587, 0.3386007249355316, 0.3217112720012665, 0.33478912711143494, 0.3175964057445526, 0.33688923716545105, 0.330964058637619, 0.3255104124546051, 0.33298707008361816, 0.3214297592639923, 0.3196769952774048, 0.3227819800376892, 0.3238556385040283, 0.32693472504615784, 0.3445647656917572, 0.3323732614517212, 0.32003507018089294, 0.33475562930107117, 0.3320826590061188, 0.3399401903152466, 0.3327116072177887, 0.3162004351615906, 0.3291887044906616, 0.3206031620502472, 0.32628875970840454, 0.3226355314254761, 0.32289108633995056, 0.33406588435173035, 0.3300870954990387, 0.3349706530570984, 0.3140355944633484, 0.32819029688835144, 0.31147170066833496, 0.3432897627353668, 0.3340785503387451, 0.3283796012401581, 0.3312298357486725, 0.33994895219802856, 0.322643518447876, 0.3271510601043701, 0.3148044943809509, 0.3369317650794983, 0.3361482620239258, 0.31631866097450256, 0.3364940285682678, 0.331266850233078, 0.3319823145866394, 0.32205238938331604, 0.3201162815093994, 0.325533926486969, 0.3220116198062897, 0.33426058292388916, 0.32188719511032104, 0.32607758045196533, 0.3368567228317261, 0.3341996967792511, 0.33817270398139954, 0.3485211133956909, 0.31580621004104614, 0.3350232243537903, 0.33642539381980896, 0.3443624675273895, 0.33930182456970215, 0.3162977993488312, 0.3302444815635681, 0.33965036273002625, 0.33180543780326843, 0.3386842906475067, 0.3192340135574341, 0.3184114396572113, 0.33170008659362793, 0.34038981795310974, 0.32190370559692383, 0.32587191462516785, 0.3249591290950775, 0.3265175223350525, 0.32746967673301697, 0.33073827624320984, 0.32750192284584045, 0.3206477761268616, 0.32076528668403625]
[0.33303067088127136, 0.3494284152984619, 0.33405354619026184, 0.3282312750816345, 0.3211935758590698, 0.33927488327026367, 0.327896386384964, 0.34072694182395935, 0.3367060124874115, 0.32884159684181213, 0.33350279927253723, 0.32315438985824585, 0.34809088706970215, 0.3294481337070465, 0.33831289410591125, 0.31815847754478455, 0.33279183506965637, 0.3479308784008026, 0.3168991208076477, 0.33735811710357666, 0.3396143913269043, 0.3400998115539551, 0.3414795994758606, 0.3205634355545044, 0.3740873336791992, 0.3353399336338043, 0.3305051922798157, 0.3272343575954437, 0.3491530120372772, 0.3284094035625458, 0.3373633325099945, 0.329039990901947, 0.3336949944496155, 0.32058975100517273, 0.333803653717041, 0.34136584401130676, 0.3283222019672394, 0.333801805973053, 0.3265749514102936, 0.3335794508457184, 0.3308466374874115, 0.32078322768211365, 0.31576845049858093, 0.3423018753528595, 0.32843002676963806, 0.3371984660625458, 0.3320159614086151, 0.33756551146507263, 0.33608195185661316, 0.3506498634815216, 0.3427160680294037]
```

I'm trying to find which setup is the best, which I'll take as the setup with the lowest median. To discard bad sets of parameters, I need to somehow tell if a list is not likely to be the best.

(I chose the median because it isn't affected by outliers as much as the mean, although I would be alright to use the mean instead.)

Which brings me to my question:

How do I find the list with the **highest probability** of having the **lowest median**?
And how can I use this to discard bad setups early on?

---

**Where I'm at so far**

I've found the median and the IQR for each list, but I'm not sure of where to go from there.
The probability that one list has a lower median will surely depend on how many values there are in the list, and neither the median or the IQR contains that information.

Update:
I've also tried modelling each list with a normal distribution, then using Welch's t-test to find the probability that one mean is lower than the other, although the distribution of values in the lists doesn't seem to be a normal distribution so it sometimes underestimates the probability massively and causes the best candidate to be removed.
For example, after ~50 simulations it gave one set of parameters a 0.1% chance of being the best, which later changed to 40% after ~200 simulations.

Here are some of the distributions of simulation results, each graph is for different setup parameters for the simulation.

[image: Distribution 1]
[image: Distribution 2]
[image: Distribution 3]
[image: Distribution 4]

Thanks! -Rlz

Comment: I've followed everything in the 'ask new questions' guide, and also checked it against https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34059/is-there-a-shorter-and-more-opinionated-version-of-how-to-ask-a-good-question/34067#34067. If there's anything I can do to improve my question please let me know!

Comment: (I am not the downvoter). How does the question arise ? We know with certainty what the median of each list is. Why probability/likely ?

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks for the comment. Each time I run a simulation I get a different value, and I need to find what setup gives the best simulation results on average (hence the median). The more simulations I run, the more accurate the median calculated is, but the longer it takes. So I'd like to find the probability that a simulation setup is the best, so I can remove bad setups early on, and speed up the process significantly!

Comment: Can you divulge how the simulations are produced and what role the parameters play in such? It might be possible to get approximations to the density as a function of the parameters and then get approximations for the median as a function of the parameters. Because, obviously, if you had an exact density $f(x, \theta)$ we would just be after $\min_\theta m(\theta)$ assuming the median depends on the parameters. Depending on how the simulation is made, one might be able to find a heuristic function that approximates the density.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Sure, I'm using a 3D simulation of race cars around a race track. Some examples of the parameters are track temperature, car top speed, and driver experience. Each simulation takes around 5 minutes to complete. In one simulation, I may give just the track temperature. In another, I might give both track temperature and top speed. The value the simulation gives is how similar the simulation was to reality (such as 0 if it guessed correctly who won, and 1 if it got it completely wrong)

Comment: After a lot of research, the best lead I've found is Welch's t-test. I believe it's only for normal distributions, but it seems to be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Update: I've implemented Welch's t-test and it seems somewhat inaccurate, after ~50 simulations it gave one set of parameters a 0.1% chance of being the best, which later changed to 40% after ~200 simulations. Another set went ~0.3% to ~25%. I assume it's because the distribution isn't normal, and Welch's t-test only works with normal distributions.

Comment: To even begin to answer this question, you need to provide information about the data-generating processes for each setup. Just using lists of data on their own will not help. You can't assess probability without some sort of data-generating process.

Comment: @Clarinetist What exactly would you like to know? It's a 3D simulation of race cars. They complete a race, the results are recorded, then compared to what happened in real life - I take the difference between the predicted and actual results, which is the output of the simulation. I have provided the distributions of these outputs, which is hopefully of use.

Comment: @Rlz Thanks for the context. You have multiple groups to be dealing with here, so it gets a bit harder to quantify. One place I'd start with is a non-parametric ANOVA, such as the Kruskal-Wallis test.